# Python SQL Selecting Data

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to test a small piece of code I wrote to search a column of a table for a specific string. The code should search the Users column of the LoginInfo table and print out the result. I have tried two versions of this code but both get different errors.

VERSION ONE:

```
    import sqlite3
    import sys
    Username = "('Hello1',)"
    print(Username)

    connection= sqlite3.connect("Logininfo.db")
    c = connection.cursor() 

    c.execute('''SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username=Hello1''') 
    for row in c :
        print(row)
```

VERSION ONE ERROR:

c.execute('''SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username=Hello1''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Hello1

VERSION TWO:

```
    import sqlite3
    import sys
    Username = "('Hello1',)"
    print(Username)

    connection= sqlite3.connect("Logininfo.db")
    c = connection.cursor() 

    c.execute("SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username="Hello1"") 
    for row in c :
        print(row)
```

VERSION TWO ERROR:

Invalid syntax error pop up highlighting Hello1

Any help would be appreciated as I'm really new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with your syntax in both cases. When you send a string into `cursor.execute` you are sending the DB a complete command. This means strings need to be quoted correctly, SQL syntax needs to be correct, etc.

This command: `SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username=Hello1` means:

"Give me the Username column from the LoginInfo table where Username matches the Hello1 column"

On the other hand this command: `SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username='Hello1'` (note the quotes) means:

"Give me the Username column from the LoginInfo table where Username = Hello1"

Your second attempt is simply invalid Python. You should be using triple quotes on the outside or escaping the quotes that are part of the query.

Comment: I have tried doing this, is this what you mean? I get an error EOL while scanning string literally.

c.execute("""SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username = "Hello1"""")

Comment: Suspect you need to be using single quotes around `Hello1`.=: `c.execute("""SELECT Username FROM LoginInfo WHERE Username = 'Hello1'""")`